# How to setup Proxy for Wi-fi router without having a dedicated computer connected all the time

Tags: networking, proxy, wifi, web-hosting, http-proxy

I don't know much about networking, proxies and WiFi setups. So spare me if I sound foolish. :)

I want to setup an open WiFi network for an office, in that create a shield for my WiFi router so that only certain websites are accessible to the user (mostly mobile phones). But I don't want to keep any dedicated computer connected to the router to check for proxies, nor I can add proxy settings to the individual user's cellphone as they will be random and different every time. But yes I would have a dedicated hosting account for the default page, if this can be used to check for proxies and do other things like block downloading, limit bandwidth and browse time.
Please let me know what are the ways to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by **check for proxies**?

Comment: by "check for proxies"  I simply mean check whether the webpage being accessed is an allowed website or not. If not then simply block it.

Comment: Something like every page request within my WiFi passes through my page and if I want it, I should be able to block or allow it programmatically.